# Tag-Completion Feature applied to Search

Tags: feature-request

Would be useful for searches to have that same feature when asking a question and assigning tags

[image]

Right now this is what it looks like when you half way typing in a tag, no attempts to complete the tag or show any other ones that exist with that prefix.
[image]

Comment: As you haven't got any responses yet maybe to try and clarify it a bit - where did you imagine the hints coming from, the tags list or the start of any question? If the latter performance might be an issue, otherwise if you had the tags in mind maybe typing `[` as the start of a tag search could trigger it.

Comment: The search bar for any question

Comment: I think that would be good too, especially when it's just triggered by the opening bracket so not on every search.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but this feature exists (somewhat) here: http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/tags